# Travando aplicativo ao adicionar uma nova página no PagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, arraylist, viewpager

Estou criando uma ViewPager usando uma PagerAdapter, e uma TabLayout para as páginas, ele cria páginas normalmente, mas quando eu tento criar uma nova página após ter definido o Adapter da ViewPager, o aplicativo crasha, alguém sabe o motivo disso? (As páginas são criadas usando uma ArrayList<>, o cumprimento da lista defini a quantidade de páginas na ViewPager)

**OnCreate**

```
    //...
    public static TabLayout tabLayout;
    public static DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    public static Context context;
    public static ArrayList<HashMap<Object,Object>> listCodePage = new ArrayList<>();

    //...OnCreate

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        context = getBaseContext();

        //configura as tab
 
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name);
        
        //Adicionando páginas para a ViewPager (Um titulo, e um texto)
        addCodePage("Tab1", "");
        addCodePage("Tab2", "");
        addCodePage("Tab3", "");
        addCodePage("Tab4", "");
        
        viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(context, listCodePage));
        
        //<ERRO>
        addCodePage("Tab5", "");
        //Quando tento criar uma página depois do Adapter ser definido, o aplicativo crasha
```

**addCodePage (Método para adicionar as páginas)**

```
    public static void addCodePage(String namePage, String textCode) {
        HashMap<Object, Object> item = new HashMap<>();
        item.put("name", namePage);
        item.put("code", textCode);
        listCodePage.add(item);
    }
```

**PagerAdapter**

```
public class PagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<HashMap<Object,Object>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<Object,Object>>();
    private Context context;

    public PagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<Object,Object>> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return super.getItemPosition(object);
    }
    
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return data.get(position).get("name").toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.pager_main, container, false);

        EditText editCode = view.findViewById(R.id.code);

        editCode.setText(data.get(position).get("code").toString());

        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas as a aceder a uma propriedade instanciada na classe do PagerAdapter ou seja o teu arraylist é uma outra referencia em memória e não a que passas para o teu construtor

tenta o seguinte

`viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(context, listCodePage)); viewPager.getAdapter().getData().add(addCodePage(namePage,textCode);`

Modifica tambem o seu método estatico para retornar algo ou seja neste caso o seu item
`HashMap<Object, Object>`;

Utilizar um método estático para alterar um arraylist que só é instanciado pela Class não é boa ideia, provavelmente o que esta acontecendo é que seu método neste momento esta a fazer o seguinte.

```
public static void addCodePage(String namePage, String textCode) {
    HashMap<Object, Object> item = new HashMap<>();
    item.put("name", namePage);
    item.put("code", textCode);
    null.add(item);
}
```

Tenta sempre evitar *side effects* e fazer com que os seu métodos retornem algo, sobretudo se forem estáticos.

Tenta fazer isto.

```
public static HashMap<Object, Object> addCodePage(String namePage, String textCode) {
    HashMap<Object, Object> item = new HashMap<>();
    item.put("name", namePage);
    item.put("code", textCode);
    return item;
}
```

e utilizar da seguinte forma no onCreate

```
litsCodePage.add(addCodePage("Tab1", ""));
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Cria tambem um Getter na PagerAdapter.

Do que entendi tambem seu Hashmap utiliza duas Strings, podes ser mais especifico e utilizar

```
HashMap<String,String>
```

Invés de:

```
HashMap<Object, Object>
```

Comment: Me ajudou muito, mas o plobema ainda não foi resolvido, o aplicativo ainda crasha, eu uso o AIDE para progamar, então não tenho suporte a LogCat, estou utilizando a ViewPager do androidx-v1.0.0, e testando em um dispositivo com sdk 29 (android 10)

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado, revi meus conceitos de progamação, mas o aplicativo ainda crasha... tive que utilizar outro código, aquele apresentava o erro
**Unknown method: getData or androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter**

Como ficou o novo código:

**Adicionar página e definir o adapter da ViewPager**

```
listCodePage.add(addCodePage("Tab1", ""));
viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(context, listCodePage));
```

**Código sem erro que eu tentei fazer (ainda crasha o app)**

```
PagerAdapter.getData().add(addCodePage("a", "b"));
```

**Código com erro**

```
viewPager.getAdapter().getData().add(addCodePage("a", "b"));
```

**getData()**

```
public class PagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

//...

    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getData()
        {
             return data;
        }

//...

}
```